# How to remove duplicates from many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I have these models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :jobs
  has_many :projects, :through => :jobs                      

end
```

---

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project

end
```

---

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :jobs
  has_many :people, :through => :jobs

end
```

---

In my `Project` model I also have this function:

```
def show_persons_projects(person_id) 
  joins([:jobs, :people]).where("people.id = ?", person_id)
end
```

The problem is that this functions often returns certain projects multiple times (depending on how many times they appear in the `jobs` table).

What is the best way to remove those duplicates from the output?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Although it is returning multiple projects but it will be for unique jobs right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
joins([:jobs, :people]).where("people.id = ?", person_id).uniq
```